# Error: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, compiler-errors

I am writing some objective-C code and i can't figure out why this does not work:

```
buttonRect = CGRectMake(0,0,100.0,100.0);//error:incompatible types in assignment
CGRect newFrame = CGRectInset(buttonRect, -0.2, -0.2);//error:incompatible type for argument 1 of CGRectInset
button.frame = newFrame;
```

buttonRect is a CGRect defined as an instance variable in my class, and button is a UIButton also defined as an instance variable. Why is this not working?
My header file:

```
//
//  MyViewController.h
//  HelloWorld
//
//  Created by RCIX on 7/10/09.
//  Copyright 2009 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *textField;
    UILabel *label;
    NSString *string;
    UIButton *button;
    CGRect *buttonRect;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect *buttonRect;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;

- (IBAction)helloButtonDown:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)helloButtonUp:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Copy and paste the declaration of buttonRect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`buttonRect` is declared as a `CGRect *` — that is, a *pointer* to a CGRect. Remove the splat and all will be well.

Comment: That worked. How could i miss something so simple? *smacks forehead*

Answer (score 1):

Double check buttonRect: sure it's not defined as CGRect.

Comment: No, it is. I made triple sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Is buttonRect defined elsewhere or do you need to give it a type when you define it?

Comment: Its an instance variable in the class i'm using.

Comment: how is it defined there? Just so we see all the info.